# Proving convergence by comparison, upper bound selection?

Tags: calculus

If we are to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9k^2+15k+4}$$ converges, is is it valid to state that $\frac{1}{9k^2+15k+4} \le \frac{1}{9k^2}$ which is known to converge by the p-test, therefore making our original series converge?

Exactly when are we allowed to do this? Can it be done with any upper bound, or are there restrictions as to when I can choose an upper bound?

Comment: Yes, that's good. To partly answer your question, we could have said that the $k$-th term is less than $\frac{1}{15k}$, but that would have been useless, since $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{15k}$ diverges.

Comment: It is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but it is too long for a comment.

Lucian's comment is extremely useful since you could notice that the roots of the denominbator are $-\frac 13$ and $-\frac 43$. So, if you decompose the general term using partial fractions, you have $$\frac{1}{9k^2+15k+4}=\frac13\Big(\frac{1}{ 3 k+1}-\frac{1}{ 3 k+4}\Big)$$ which telescopes.

Then $$\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{1}{9k^2+15k+4}=\frac{p}{4 (3 p+4)}$$